# Regexp for chroot-like path building in a Linux environment

Tags: regex, linux, security, language-agnostic

Consider the following security problem:

I have a static base path (`/home/username/`) to which I append a user-controlled sub-path (say `foo/bar.txt`). The content of this file is then read and presented to the user.

In the case described the full path would be: `/home/username/foo/bar.txt`

Now to the problem. I want to control so that the full path is always a subdirectory of the static base path. In other words I don't want the user to supply a path such that the base path is escaped.

The following full path is OK:

```
/home/username/foo/bar.txt
```

Whereas this one is one is clearly not safe:

```
/home/username/foo/../../../etc/passwd
```

To complicate matters further the proper solution of chroot:ing to the base path is not available. Due to various reasons the only available solution is to use a regexp to differentiate between safe and unsafe paths.

**Given the problem outlined above, what is the proper regexp?**

Please note:

- The code will run under Linux. The path separator is hence `/`.
- The question is totally language agnostic.
- Please do not suggest other ways to solve the problem. I know that there are alternative better ways to solve it (such as chroot:ing), but this question is restricted to the regexp solution only.

Comment: There is no such thing as a language-agnostic regular expression. What regex implementation are you using?

Comment: Not all regex flavors that are PCRE are the same. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Bart: If your answer should happen to be dependent on which PCRE regex flavor that is being use (highly unlikely), then please state that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reject it outright, just strip any "../" from the path, like this :

```
sed -e 's/\..\///g'
```

You should be aware that there could be files in the directory hierarchy that you allow that are linked to directories outside of that hierarchy.

Without using chroot I don't think there is a way that you can guarantee for it to be totally safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reject any user input that matches `/(^|\/)\.\.(\/|$)/`

That means: if it contains `/../` or begins with `../` or ends with `/..` or is `..`

Comment: But you have to make sure, that you prepend '/home/username/', otherwise `~/something` or `/var/log` will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can't be done using just one single regexp. Regexps can't count anything, while here you definitely need to count the number of ../

However, you may try using recursive regexps and check for recursive nesting of ([[:alpha:]]+/..), like [[:alpha:]]+(\R)|..

I agree that it is better to forbid ../ at all